# How do I sync Redis master to another standalone Redis instance?

Tags: linux, redis, synchronization, replication

I have a Master/Slave environment that I would like to sync (daily) with another standalone Redis instance.
I know that I can dump the data, transfer it to the other server than import the data.
Is there a way to stream the data from Redis to Redis?

Comment: Like some program with scheduler to sync the data ?

Comment: @PRATHAPS or a SHELL script.

Comment: Replication is possible - https://redis.io/topics/replication
Not sure about sync

Comment: why not make the standalone Redis a slave of the Redis you want to sync?

Comment: @for_stack The Redis I want to sync I don't have control over its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your instance a slave of the Redis that you want to sync.

You don't need to config the master. Just use the `SLAVEOF host port` command to make your instance a slave of the Redis that you want to sync. When the synchronization is done, use the `SLAVEOF NO ONE` command to stop the replication.